# Proving $f_n(z)=z^n$ does not converge uniformly

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that the sequence $f_n(z)=z^n$ converges non-uniformly in the set $[0,1[$.

$f_n(z)\to 0$ for $z\in[0,1[$. Let $z_n=\Big(\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{n}}}\Big)$. Then we have:

$|f_n(z_n)-f(z_n)|=z^n_n=\frac{1}{2}=\epsilon$

Then the sequence does not converge uniformly.

**Question**:

Why is this procedure legitimate? Is there any theorem or corollary backing up the step?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This procedure simply shows that the definition of uniform convergence is not satisfied. Write down the definition and you will se that what is done here is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: @Crostul                When I take the limit of the function sequence $f_n$ the z is treated as fixed number. However by replacing it with a sequence it is no longer fixed once it depends on $n$. That is where my confusion takes place.

Answer (score 1):

Use the contrapositive. $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ if and only if for each $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb N^*$ s.t. whenever $n > N$, $\vert f_n (z) - f(z) \vert < \varepsilon $ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Now the contrapositive should be

> $f_n$ fails to converge uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$ if and only if there is some $\varepsilon_0 > 0$, for all $N \in \mathbb N^*$, there exists $n > N$ and some $x_N$ that $\vert f_n(x_N) - f(x_N)\vert \geqslant \varepsilon_0$.

In the question, in the proof a sequence $(x_n)$ is found, which is corresponding to the $x_N$ in the contrapositive above. To  match the assumption in the contrapositive, we actually only need to pick 1 $x_N$ for each $N$, so the points are not fixed anymore.